# Not able to resolve MySQL error #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

My query seems to be ok as far as my knowledge goes:

```
CREATE TABLE PORTAL_NOTES (
    id numeric NOT NULL,
    school_id numeric,
    syear numeric(4,0),
    title character varying(255),
    content character varying(5000),
    sort_order numeric,
    published_user numeric,
    published_date timestamp(0),
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    published_profiles character varying(255)
);
```

But I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1) , start_date date, end_date date, published_profiles characte' at line 9
```

Can anyone help me debug the problem here?

Comment: `timestamp` does not need a length.

Comment: works for me! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/161c6

Comment: Just off the top of my head, shouldn't it just be timestamp, not timestamp(0)?

Comment: I am sorry... I had the same doubt... But since this was a code I had downloaded from github, I thought even timestamp should have length specified...

Comment: Anyway, *this* error message does not belong to *that* query.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
CREATE TABLE PORTAL_NOTES (
    id numeric NOT NULL,
    school_id numeric,
    syear numeric(4,0),
    title character varying(255),
    content character varying(5000),
    sort_order numeric,
    published_user numeric,
    published_date timestamp,
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    published_profiles character varying(255)
);
```

Issue is because you have set length in `timestamp(0)`, this don't need length.

Comment: But it makes no difference if you provide one

Comment: Server versions prior to 5.6 might choke on a length, even if 0, since length was not supported before 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE PORTAL_NOTES (
    id numeric NOT NULL,
    school_id numeric,
    syear numeric(4,0),
    title character varying(255),
    content character varying(5000),
    sort_order numeric,
    published_user numeric,
    published_date timestamp,
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    published_profiles character varying(255)
);
```

Use above code..
I think your mysql version is lower, so it does not support length..
Update mysql version or you can use query as above.